# Access to a class in a classpath of a fat Spring Boot app from a nested library

Tags: spring-boot, classpath

I created an implementation for a class, referenced by system property `java.util.logging.config.class` in a project submodule. Java cannot find this class because `bootJar` packed it to `BOOT-INF/lib`:

```
Logging configuration class "com.evil.logging.JulBootstrap" failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class com.evil.logging.JulBootstrap
getBootstrapResource not available on ClassLoader
```

I've read about possibility to unpack certain libs to a temporary directory with `requiresUnpack`:

```
tasks.named("bootJar") {
    requiresUnpack '**/jruby-complete-*.jar'
}
```

I think it is too late for JUL logging to unpack jar by a framework. Is there a way to extract a class from a library to a fat jar root classpath?